How to debug this error while using Hypergeometric Confluent function?
I am trying to define this function using hypergeometric confluent function in the scipy.special library:
def Fl(x,l,p):
  F=sc.hyp1f1(l+1-(1j*p),2*(l+1),-2*1j*x)
  s=sc.gamma(l+1+(1j*p))/math.gamma(2*(l+1))
  d=cmath.exp((math.pi*p)/2)*(2**l)*(x**(l+1))*cmath.exp((1j*x)+(1j*sigl(l)))
  F1=F*s*d
  return F1

But getting error:
36 def Fl(x,l,p):
---> 37   F=sc.hyp1f1(l+1-(1j*p),2*(l+1),-2*1j*x)
     38   s=sc.gamma(l+1+(1j*p))/math.gamma(2*(l+1))
     39   d=cmath.exp((math.pi*p)/2)*(2**l)*(x**(l+1))*cmath.exp((1j*x)+(1j*sigl(l)))

TypeError: ufunc 'hyp1f1' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Can someone please help me from figuring out what the problem is? What are the kind of inputs this function is supposed to take?

hyp1f1 only accepts real-valued a and b (the third argument, x, can be complex), see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.hyp1f1.html
In [1]: from scipy.special import hyp1f1

In [2]: hyp1f1(1, 2, 1j)
Out[2]: (0.8414709848078965+0.45969769413186023j)

In [3]: hyp1f1(1j, 2, 1j)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 hyp1f1(1j, 2, 1j)

TypeError: ufunc 'hyp1f1' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

